# Is there a way to match the value and description of a code in a dataframe to the code in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have 2 data frames. One is the details of all calls for service in 2021 and I named it data_1. And the second is a code file that will allow me to convert coded fields into normal descriptions and I named it code_file. The code_file looks something like this

| id | codevalue | descr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc.1 | 021 | Action taken |
| abc.1 | 078 | search and rescue |
| abc.1 | 784 | transport |

The data_1 df with details for all calls looks something like this

| state | city | abc.1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FL | Orlando | 021 |
| FL | Miami | 078 |
| FL | Miami | 784 |

How do I combine the two dataframes in a way that if there is match on codevalue and abc.1 then the descr column is added in too? Basically the code_file should allow me to convert coded fields into normal descriptions. I just provided one value but All the values in id column is actually a column in data_1 and these columns have the values from the codevalue column.

The output should look something like this

| state | abc.1 | city | descr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FL | 021 | Orlando | Action taken |
| FL | 078 | Miami | search and rescue |
| FL | 784 | Miami | transport |

I don't know where to start. I never had to work with dataframes which have coded fields for columns in another dataframe

Comment: `dplyr::left_join(data_1, code_file, by = c("abc.1" = "codevalue"))`

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your first dataframe `df1` and your second `df2`. You essentially want to "merge" df1 and df2 on the "abc.1" column. I assume you don't want the other columns from df1 in the result, just the "descr" column with the looked up value, so we select only the columns we want ("abc.1" and "descr").

Example:

```py
# Merge the two dataframes based on the common column "abc.1"
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='codevalue', right_on='abc.1', how='right')

df2['descr'] = merged_df['description']

# Print the result
print(df2)
```

Comment: I am afraid this won't work. Basically the code_file should allow me to convert coded fields into normal descriptions. I just provided one value but All the values in "id" column is actually a separate column in "data_1" and these columns have the values from the "codevalue" column if that makes sense.

Comment: How about the edited answer? Are there multiple abc.1, abc.2, etc columns that need to also be matched on the `id` column in addition to the codevalue <-> abc.1 linkage?

Comment: Yes the values in id column are separate columns in data_1. And these columns have a unique codevalue that will show us what the incident type was